# BA.startDiscovery() returns "null" for some device names

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am a beginner Android App programmer and I am working on BLE app to communicate with the microcontroller (ESP32).

I have managed to get the APP going (enabling the BLE and Location permissions) and got to the point where I am able to scan nearby BLE devices.

I have noticed that when I start discovering nearby BLE devices, some devices are detected as "null"

The debug logs when I click "SCAN" button:

```
E/SCAN BUTTON: Clicked 
E/CHECK: CHECKING LOCATION PERMISSION 
E/INFO: LOCATION PERMISSION ALREADY GRANTED: 
E/INFO: LOCATION PERMISSION IS OK, START BLE DISCOVERY 
I/BluetoothAdapter: startDiscovery
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
E/BroadcastReceiver: SCANNING IN PROGRESS
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = DESKTOP-KPO80BS
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 64:6E:69:78:B9:54
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = null
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 5E:52:CD:CD:EB:EA
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = [LG] webOS TV UP75003LF
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 4C:BC:E9:4E:62:17
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = null
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 7F:CA:0B:28:8E:86
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = CGATES-DV8947
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 10:76:36:B5:7C:A4
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = [LG] webOS TV UP75003LF
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 7C:5E:DC:65:EB:E9
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = JBL Bar 5.1_5883
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 7E:96:FC:6A:9F:A9
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
I/System.out: DEVICE NAME FOUND = null
I/System.out: DEVICE MAC FOUND = 4E:AE:EC:2B:D9:52
E/CALLBACK: onReceive
E/BroadcastReceiver: DISCOVERY FINISHED
```

How it looks on my phone (Simulating on my Physical Samsung Flip 2).
[image]

My build. gradle (Here you can see the target SDK and minSDK:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.location_test_v2'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.location_test_v2"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.6"
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.7.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}

configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
}
```

The callback function that is being executed when I call BA.startDiscovery() :

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver devicesFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.e("CALLBACK", "onReceive");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {

                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                String deviceName = device.getName();
                String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address

                //Log.e("BroadcastReceiver", "DEVICE FOUND: ",deviceName);
                System.out.print("DEVICE NAME FOUND = ");
                System.out.println(deviceName);
                System.out.print("DEVICE MAC FOUND = ");
                System.out.println(deviceHardwareAddress);
                list.add(deviceName);
                
            }
            else if(BA.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)){
                Log.e("BroadcastReceiver", "DISCOVERY FINISHED ");
                ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list);
                listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
            else if(BA.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)){
                listview.setAdapter(null);
                Log.e("BroadcastReceiver", "SCANNING IN PROGRESS");
            }
        }
    };
```

I have found some other people complaining about this but no clear solution has been provided:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240485116

I hope to get some advice regarding how to handle this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like you are confusing things. It is not the device object itself which is null but its name property. When you detect a device which has no name or an empty string just display it as *Unknown* or *Unnamed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Bluetooth LE device can transmit its name in the advertisement message, but it does not have to. If "DEVICE NAME" is null, use "DEVICE MAC" instead.